# Not Found Exception Jinja2 (Flask app)

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I've searched for a solution but everywhere users had some problems with project structure. I also checked my project out and It was completely correct. This is my project structure:

```
/setup.py
/virtuale
/projectpackage
    /templates
        /home.html
    /static
    /assets
    init.py
    view.py
```

---

```
__init__.py:

from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

import projectpackage.views
```

---

```
views.py:
    from projectpackage import app
    from flask import url_for, render_template


    @app.route('/')
    def index():
        return render_template('home')
```

And this is the error I'm getting:

```
jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound
jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: home
```

Solution: render_template() takes a full filename (template name) as its first argument. (like `home.html` not `home`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The render_template method requires a full file name, you'll need to append the .html to the file name.  Change this

```
@app.route('/')
    def index():
        return render_template('home')
```

to:

```
@app.route('/')
    def index():
        return render_template('home.html')
```